# Htaccess masking real folder name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have one problem I need advice on.

I want to mask folder names in my website running joomla 3.8 using htaccess rules for example if I open console in google chrome and visit tab Sources I will see structure of my website with following folder:
templates/temlate_name/

I have managed to mask folder name partially using following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /real_folder_name/

RewriteRule ^real_folder_name/(.*)$ fake_folder_name/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^fake_folder_name/(.*)$ real_folder_name/$1
```

and that really changed folder names without breaking site when I go to developer console sources section via chrome

But if I open source code of page I still see real urls example

```
 <link href="/cache/com_templates/templates/ra_template/5791a87f26badb650e42f3790edac52d.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/media/mod_languages/css/template.css?236ca17ae906371918cc54bf64db39c8" />
```

Also this method doesn't work if I want to hide for example second folder hidden_folder/still_visible_folder

What am I doing wrong how to manifest changes to source code also ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> But if I open source code of page I still see real urls example

Source could will be as it is .

> What am I doing wrong how to manifest changes to source code also ?

Actually , a server receiving a request then first checks whether the request is matching an existing file.

If so, the web server sends the file content back to the browser, If not,server will return an error message to the browser .

Between these two steps you could make specific configuration like handling error requests by sending all of them to custom file and that custom file content , in this case, will be a content that suould back to the browser.

So , when you change the existing file with fake file but redirect a fake file internally to original path , that will happened before sending back a response to browser and nothing will happen in source code then the content of original file will back to browser.

Comment: I see Mohammed, I will play a little bit more and report back if I succeed.